# Update (Javascript) collection column in MongoDB with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, mongodb

When attempting to update a mongoDB collection with an array as the value, the update fails silently.

This does not work:

```
var arr = ["test","test1","test2"];
$.ajax('http://my.mongodb.com/collection?id=80a2c727de877ac9' , {
      type: "PUT",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        mykey: arr
      }),
      success: function() {
        // Do something
      }, 
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
```

This does:

```
$.ajax('http://my.mongodb.com/collection?id=80a2c727de877ac9' , {
      type: "PUT",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        mykey: "test"
      }),
      success: function() {
        // Do something
      }, 
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Check what the request returns to catch these errors.

Comment: @JonasWilms - I get a 200 ok

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I need to stringify the array before stringifying it within the ajax data:

```
var arr = ["test","test1","test2"];
arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
$.ajax('http://mordor.fmr.com:8030/techtest?id=80a2c727de877ac9' , {
      type: "PUT",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        assignedTechs: arr
      }),
      success: function() {
        // Do something
      }, 
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
```